# Count the number of value changes within the past n days

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to count the number of `num` that don't equal the previous `num` within the past d days, preferably with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

My data looks like this:

```
d <- 3
   df1 <- structure(list(LET = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                       .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
                   day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
                   num = c(5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1)), 
              class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
              row.names = c(NA, -10L))
    LET day num
 1:   a   1   5
 2:   a   2   6
 3:   a   3   6
 4:   a   4   7
 5:   a   5   7
 6:   b   1   1
 7:   b   2   1
 8:   b   3   3
 9:   b   4   1
10:   b   5   1
```

And I can use shift to say whether or not a `num` equals its lagged value, whether or not a `num` has changed:

```
df1[,hasChanged := num!=shift(num, n=1, fill=FALSE), by='LET']
```

But I'd like to count the number of `num` changes where day <= currentRowDay & day > currentRowDay - d , by `LET`.

Output would look like this (hasChanged column is optional):

```
df1[,NumberOfChangesPast3Days := c(1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),]

    LET day num hasChanged NumberOfChangesPast3Days
 1:   a   1   5       TRUE                        1
 2:   a   2   6       TRUE                        2
 3:   a   3   6      FALSE                        2
 4:   a   4   7       TRUE                        2
 5:   a   5   7      FALSE                        1
 6:   b   1   1       TRUE                        1
 7:   b   2   1      FALSE                        1
 8:   b   3   3       TRUE                        2
 9:   b   4   1       TRUE                        2
10:   b   5   1      FALSE                        2
```

Comment: I believe this is not entirely clear - you need to post your expected output.

Comment: Posted expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is using `Reduce` with `shift`:

```
df1[, N_Changes := Reduce(`+`, shift(hasChanged, n = 0:(d-1), fill = FALSE))
    , by = LET]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df1
>     LET day num hasChanged N_Changes
>  1:   a   1   5       TRUE         1
>  2:   a   2   6       TRUE         2
>  3:   a   3   6      FALSE         2
>  4:   a   4   7       TRUE         2
>  5:   a   5   7      FALSE         1
>  6:   b   1   1       TRUE         1
>  7:   b   2   1      FALSE         1
>  8:   b   3   3       TRUE         2
>  9:   b   4   1       TRUE         2
> 10:   b   5   1      FALSE         2
> ```

Comment: please, note that using `shift()` will only return correct answers if the days are continguous, i.e., without any gaps.

Answer (score 3):

All the solution posted so far are using the `shift()` function which requires that the sequence of days is contiguous, i.e., has no gaps. The answers return the expected result only by chance because the sample dataset does not have any gaps.

The OP has clearly stated that he likes

> to count the number of num changes where day <= currentRowDay &
>   day > currentRowDay - d

This can be achieved even for gapped data by *aggregating in a non-equi self-join* which aggregates in a rollling window of 3 days (not 3 rows!):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[
  , c("hasChanged", "day_start") := 
    .(c(TRUE, diff(num) != 0), day - d), by = LET][
      , sprintf("NumberOfChangesPast%iDays", d) := 
        .SD[.SD, on = .(LET, day > day_start, day <= day), sum(hasChanged), 
            by = .EACHI]$V1][]
```

> ```
>     LET day num hasChanged day_start NumberOfChangesPast3Days
>  1:   a   1   5       TRUE        -2                        1
>  2:   a   2   6       TRUE        -1                        2
>  3:   a   3   6      FALSE         0                        2
>  4:   a   4   7       TRUE         1                        2
>  5:   a   5   7      FALSE         2                        1
>  6:   b   1   1       TRUE        -2                        1
>  7:   b   2   1      FALSE        -1                        1
>  8:   b   3   3       TRUE         0                        2
>  9:   b   4   1       TRUE         1                        2
> 10:   b   5   1      FALSE         2                        2
> ```

For gapped data like, e.g.,

```
df2 <- structure(list(LET = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                      .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
                      day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L),
                      num = c(5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1)), 
                 class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

the code

```
setDT(df2)[
  , c("hasChanged", "day_start") := 
    .(c(TRUE, diff(num) != 0), day - d), by = LET][
      , sprintf("NumberOfChangesPast%iDays", d) := 
        .SD[.SD, on = .(LET, day > day_start, day <= day), sum(hasChanged), 
            by = .EACHI]$V1][]
```

returns

> ```
>     LET day num hasChanged day_start NumberOfChangesPast3Days
>  1:   a   1   5       TRUE        -2                        1
>  2:   a   2   6       TRUE        -1                        2
>  3:   a   3   6      FALSE         0                        2
>  4:   a   5   7       TRUE         2                        1
>  5:   a   7   7      FALSE         4                        1
>  6:   b   1   1       TRUE        -2                        1
>  7:   b   2   1      FALSE        -1                        1
>  8:   b   3   3       TRUE         0                        2
>  9:   b   4   1       TRUE         1                        2
> 10:   b   6   1      FALSE         3                        1
> ```

Note that `day_start` is not included in the rolling window as the OP has requested a left open interval.

Answer (score 2):

That would be one way of using `data.table`'s `shift`:

```
library(data.table)

df1[, hasChanged := num != shift(num, n=1, fill=FALSE), by = LET][
  , NumberOfChangesPast3Days := colSums(do.call(rbind, shift(hasChanged, (d-1):0)), na.rm = TRUE), 
  by = LET
  ]
```

Output:

```
    LET day num hasChanged NumberOfChangesPast3Days
 1:   a   1   5       TRUE                        1
 2:   a   2   6       TRUE                        2
 3:   a   3   6      FALSE                        2
 4:   a   4   7       TRUE                        2
 5:   a   5   7      FALSE                        1
 6:   b   1   1       TRUE                        1
 7:   b   2   1      FALSE                        1
 8:   b   3   3       TRUE                        2
 9:   b   4   1       TRUE                        2
10:   b   5   1      FALSE                        2
```

Comment: Please, note that using `shift()` will only return correct answers if the days are continguous, i.e., without any gaps.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, indeed - this works only for the consecutive days, have upvoted your answer.